# How to compare two SharePoint lists and return matching list items

Tags: ajax, rest, sharepoint, datatables, sharepoint-online

I have two identically structured SharePoint Online 2016 lists, and I would like to compare those lists and return the matching fields using REST API. The goal is to click a button, which will:

1. Get the current user's ID
2. In List A, get the Position and the Location fields where ID equals current user's ID
3. In List B, get all items from the Position and Location fields
4. Compare the values in the Position and the Location fields from both lists, and return *any* matching list items
5. Display matching results in a jQuery DataTable

The fields in both lists are choice columns with identical names.

I can retrieve the data from both lists via REST, but **I'm not sure how to implement the comparing/matching step**. Any insight would be appreciated. I'm open to alternative approaches as well.

```
<input type="button" id="onClick" value="Get Matches">
```

```
// Get Location and Position fields from List A where user ID equals current user
$(function(){
    $("#onClick").click(function(){
        var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId; 
        var ListAurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=location/Title,position/Title&$expand=location/Title,position/Title&$top=5000&$filter=(AuthorId eq '" + userId + "')";
        $.ajax({
            url: ListAurl,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                 "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
        
        function onSuccess(data) {
            var ListAItems = data.d.results;
        }
        function onError(error) {
        }

// Get Location and Position fields from List B
        var ListBurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListB')/items?$select=location/Title,position/Title&$expand=location/Title,position/Title&$top=5000";
        $.ajax({
            url: ListBurl,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });

        function onSuccess(data) {
            var ListBItems = data.d.results;
        }

        function onError(error) {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use filter function in js.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

The outer list uses the filter function to traverse the value of another list in the filter and return the value that meets your requirements

Of course you can also directly use the double for loop：

```
 for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < listb.length; j++) {
           //do compare action                 
        }
    }
```